# Change words on text view

Tags: java, android

I have a problem - I use a webservice to display some information in a `TextView` , but in many texts I have words like "Ž" , and when I show it on the device, that character appears something like "?". I want to know how to change this "Ž" into another character to show it correctly.

This is my main:

```
TextView text1=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
TextView text2=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textNom);
TextView text3=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textPost);
TextView text4=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textDdn);

text1.setText(players.getNm()); 
text2.setText(Html.fromHtml( players.getNom()).toString());
text3.setText(Html.fromHtml( layers.getPost()).toString());
text4.setText(players.getDdn());
```

And this is my xml file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textPost"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textDdn"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textDdn"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="Wydad_Test"
    android:textColor="#000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textNom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="Wydad_Test"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textPost"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textNom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textDdn"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Wydad_Test"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: The code you showed seems alright. I think you might have encoding problem somewhere. Take a look at what Html.fromHtml returns.

Comment: yes i use html format ana i replaces  this word but still the same problem

Comment: What is your HTML encoding?